# LLM colab producing error NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, openai-api, openai-gym, large-language-model

I've been trying to run the https://github.com/google-research/google-research/blob/master/language_model_uncertainty/KnowNo_Demo.ipynb colab. However every time I try running `_, demo_mc_gen_raw = lm(demo_mc_gen_prompt, stop_seq=['We:'], logit_bias={})` which is in the Access the LLM uncertainty part of the colab, I always get this error

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[22], line 85
     82 demo_mc_gen_prompt = demo_mc_gen_prompt.replace('{scene_objects}', scene_objects)
     84 # Generate multiple choices
---> 85 _, demo_mc_gen_raw = lm(demo_mc_gen_prompt, stop_seq=['We:'], logit_bias={})
     86 demo_mc_gen_raw = demo_mc_gen_raw.strip()
     87 demo_mc_gen_full, demo_mc_gen_all, demo_add_mc_prefix = process_mc_raw(demo_mc_gen_raw)

Cell In[17], line 50
     48         print('Timeout, retrying...')
     49         pass
---> 50 return response, response["choices"][0]["text"].strip()

UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'response' where it is not associated with a value
```

```
"/knowNo/KnowNo_Demo.ipynb", line 348, in <module>
    "execution_count": null,
                       ^^^^
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

Does anyone have any idea on how I can fix this?

I tried using the debugger to see what was going wrong, but I can't really tell what is up with it or how to solve it. I also don't think it is an issue with my open ai key.